# Way to lock Terraform state file from being overwritten

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have a shared terraform state file which has information about the VPC id, subnet id etc, this is a shared state stored in Amazon S3 bucket. We use the state information to spin up individual clusters in AWS. Initial terraform file shouldn't be overwritten by anyone except the admin, is there a way to lock the state in s3, so there is no changes/modification made to the existing state ? Is this feasible ? Or is there a way around ! Thanks

Comment: Documentation here mentions how to achieve state locking with the S3 backend: https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform itself cannot control the access to a state snapshot in S3, but you can use [S3 bucket IAM policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html) to control what operations are allowed either for an entire S3 bucket or for a particular path in an S3 bucket, using IAM users and roles.

There's more information in the Amazon guide [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/).

In your case, I think you would have two sets of policy statements that are each associated with a different set of IAM principals (users or roles). The first would grant write access to your administrators, which could look like the example in the guide for console access:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/stateobject.tfstate"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The second would be to grant read access to those who need it, which would be very similar to the above but would exclude the `s3:PutObject` and `s3:DeleteObject` actions, so that the associated principals only have read access.

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't support locking the object. Instead, we can minimize the change of shared states file by separate as another terraform project.

In this situation, the new terraform stack can be referenced through a [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html). As a normal user, they only require to have the read access on `s3://terraform-state-prod/network/terraform.tfstate` when they apply.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "terraform-state-prod"
    key    = "network/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  # ...
  subnet_id = data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnet_id
}
```